# C# Windows Form Application not reading files correctly from Linux-based server

Tags: c#, linux, winforms

I've made a windows form application which does some stuff. All works well accept when I want to load files from a remote server which is linux-based.

When loading and just listing the files in a textbox I get different results depending on if I've loaded the files from local storage or from the linux-based server. When done locally the application lists the file in the correct alphabetical order, but not when read from the server. It then just lists the files randomly. (Of course not randomly but you get it, not by file size or file name or anything distinguishable)

Why is this? And what, if anything, can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried sorting the list of files before displaying?

Comment: can you show some example of file paths which you get

Comment: Are you sorting the results at all or just assuming they should be in alphabetical order?

Comment: Unless you've specifically *asked* some component to give you the files in a particular order (in which case, show the code), in most cases you should assume that the values returned from any API are sorted randomly - unless it's documented otherwise or you implement a sort yourself.

Comment: E.g. [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/4cyf24ss.aspx): "The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the [`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.array.sort.aspx) method if a specific sort order is required."

Answer (score 1):

Sort the file before displaying;

```
var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(folder)    
               orderby file descending 
               select file;
```

or

```
   var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder)
                     .OrderByDescending(filename => filename);
```

for net 4.0 or later.

Comment: `string[] filePathArray = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder)                  .OrderByDescending(filename => filename);`
doesn't work for me :S what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just sorting my filePathArray actually did the job. `Array.Sort(filePathArray);`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because I was storing the file paths in an array and then displaying the contents of that array, sorting the string array was sufficient.

```
Array.Sort(filePathArray);
```

Comment: I'm going to accept my answer in 2 days since it worked for me. Or should I accept another answer as being of more help to the general public? Please advise.